# Symfony2 PHPWord response

Tags: symfony, phpword

I am trying to generate a docx document on Symfony2, using the PHPWord bundle.

In my controller, I succeed in returning a docx file, but it is empty, I think it comes from my faulty response format.

```
public function indexAction($id)
{
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
    $section = $PHPWord->addSection();

    $section->addText(htmlspecialchars(
    '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
        . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
        . '(Albert Einstein)'
    ));


  // Saving the document
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

return new Response($objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx'), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'));
}
```

Comment: What does $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx') return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer.

I achieve using the 2nd method, which is in my opinion the best.
I just have to return a response, otherwise the file was generated, but stuck in the web directory.
Using this response, everything was fine and a download prompt appeared, with the "full" file.

Here's my code :

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$section = $PHPWord->addSection();

$section->addText(htmlspecialchars(
            '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
                . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
                . '(Albert Einstein)'
        ));

    // Saving the document
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');     
    $filename="MyAwesomeFile.docx";
    $objWriter->save($filename, 'Word2007', true);

    $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(). "/../web/" . $filename;
    $content = file_get_contents($path);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$filename);
    $response->setContent($content);
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this class

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class WordResponse extends Response
{
    /**
     * WordResponse constructor.
     * @param string $name The name of the word file
     * @param PhpWord $word
     */
    public function __construct($name, &$word)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Set default zip library.
        if( !class_exists('ZipArchive')){
            Settings::setZipClass(Settings::PCLZIP);
        }

        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($word, 'Word2007');

        //Set headers.
        $this->headers->set("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
        $this->headers->set("Content-Type", 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        $this->headers->set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", 'binary');
        $this->headers->set("Cache-Control", 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        $this->headers->set("Expires", '0');

        $this->sendHeaders();
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }
}
```

Then in your controller do:

```
return new WordResponse($phpWord, "filename.docx");
```

Answer (score 0):

`PHPWord->save()` returns a true value so that would be why your file is not being downloaded. With your `return new Response()` you are setting the content of your response to true (the result of your `save` call) which is why your response is empty.

You have 2 (and probably more that I haven't thought of) options to generate and download this file..

**1**. ***Save your file to a temp folder and server from there***

```
$filename = sprintf(
    '%s%sDoc-Storage%s%s.%s',
    sys_get_temp_dir(),
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    uniqid(),
    'docx'
);

$objWriter->save($filename);

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filename);
```

For more info on the BinaryFileResponse see [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files).

**2**. ***Ignore Symfony and serve directly via the PHPWord action***

```
$objWriter->save($filename, 'Word2007', true);
exit();
```

The `->save` method provides all of the actions to download the generated file internally (see [the code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/PhpWord.php#L304-L312)) so all you need to do is set the format and the third parameter to true and it will handle all of the headers for you. Granted it won't be returning a Symfony response but you will be exiting out before you get to that exception.