# How to download DOCX document from Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, download, docx

I have an Symfony controller to upload `.docx` files and another to download it.

My symfony controller to download the file looks like that:

```
public function getDocumentationAction(Request $request, $uriFile) {


    $filename = $uriFile;
    $path = $this->getParameter('documents_directory').'/'.$filename;

    $file = file_get_contents($path);

    $response = new Response($file);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    return $response;

}
```

The problem is that when the file is downloaded, the format of the file is not the correct. For example, if I upload a docx containing `test` word, when I download this file, I get a strange `.docx` starting with:

> PK!›¸ï7f [Content_Types].xml ¢(†¥TÀn¬0ºWÍ?DæVâ°á™™˙8∂H•`Ï
>   XıKˆÚ˙˚nDUA*Â)YÔÃÏÏƒÉ—⁄öl    1iÔJ÷/z,'Ω“nV≤è…K~œ≤Ñ¬)aºÉím ±—˙j0ŸHuªT≤9bx‡<…9Xë
>   ¿Q•Ú—
>   §◊8„A»O1~€Î›qÈÇ√k6<A%≥Á5}ﬁ*â`À∑kÆíâåñI)_:ıÉ%ﬂ1‘ŸúIs“

If I convert this strange docx file to PDF, using for example: https://online2pdf.com/en/convert-docx-to-pdf I get a PDF with `test` word inside, so the information is in it, but it's not showing properly.

My Symfony upload controller seems to work well, since I can access file from server, and see properly the content.

Answer (score 1):

You must return a binary response. 
You have twice choices for this :

```
$fileName = 'your_docx.docx';
$path = $this->getParameter('documents_directory').'/'.$filename;
$content = file_get_contents($path);

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$filename);
$response->setContent($content);
return $response;
```

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254080/6635967

An another method is  :

```
    $fileName = 'your_docx.docx';
    $temp_file = $this->getParameter('documents_directory').'/'.$filename;
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($temp_file);
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $fileName
    );

    return $response;
```

Found here : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/361/how-to-create-a-word-file-with-php-in-symfony-3